# Why is the onclick event still going to url even after pressing cancel?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, onclick

I have a link which has a `onclick` function

```html
<a onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"
        href="#"
        data-bind="ifnot: ($data.borrowed_amount > 0 || $data.status == 0), click: $root.deleteMoneyBorrowed">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

When I click it, it shows that "are you sure you want to delete" but when I press cancel it still goes ahead and deletes, dont know how to stop deleting if I press cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 events bound to the `<a>` tag. One event is the default onclick event and the other you have set up to be bound to the item via knockout. You need to have a single bound event.

In this even you create the confirmation. Then, if the confirmation is equal to true, process the delete method.

So, to be direct, remove the onclick attribute. In the deleteMoneyBorrowed function,

```
if(window.confirm('...')) {
    deleteMoneyBorrowed();
    console.log('user confirmed');
} else {
    console.log('user cancelled');
}
```

Also, it's best you move your class definition to the span up to the parent `<a>` and just remove the span.

```
<a href="#" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" 
    data-bind="ifnot: ($data.borrowed_amount > 0 || $data.status == 0),
    click: $root.deleteMoneyBorrowed"></a>
```

Here is a fiddle as an example : https://jsfiddle.net/vk4nzo05/

Comment: Can you show me a js fiddle of your example? Sorry if its too much, but its not working on my computer

Comment: added a link to a fiddle

Comment: Thanks alot, did not work at first, when i did databind goforit, added $root.goforit it worked :D, I am accepting the answer, but you can change it if you want :D, thanks alot!

Comment: it works...just be sure you hit 'run' before you click the link...by making the 'change' it forced a run in the background.